# Question regarding order of evaluation of elements in Group Action example

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, group-actions

I'm learning about group actions (just the basics right now) and an example has come up in the book for which I do not see how the algebra works the way it does. I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking but would like some clarification, nevertheless. The example is set up as follows:

> Suppose $G$ acts on a set $X$. For any two sets $X$ and $Y$ recall that $Y^X$ is the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$. If $G$ acts on $X$, we claim that $$g \cdot f(x) = f(g^{-1} \cdot x)$$ defines a group action of $G$ on $Y^X$

Now in proving the second property (the non-identity one) from the function definition of a group action we see that for $g,h \in G$ and $f \in Y^X$

$$\begin{align}
g \cdot (h \cdot f)(x) &= h \cdot f(g^{-1} \cdot x) \\
&= f(h^{-1} \cdot (g^{-1} \cdot x)) \\
&= f(h^{-1}g^{-1} \cdot x) \\
&= f((gh)^{-1} \cdot x)\\
& = gh \cdot f(x).
\end{align}$$

Now, why is it that we don't get, for the second expression (after the first equality) that $g \cdot f(h^{-1} \cdot x)$? I ask because up to this point every expression in the text has been evaluated right to left, however this seems to be evaluated left to right in terms of the elements of $G$ in acting on the element of $Y^X$.

Comment: I would tend to write the definition as $(g \cdot f)(x) = f(g^{-1} \cdot x)$ since $g \cdot f(x)$ would usually be interpreted as taking $f(x)$ and letting $g$ act on it.  (But then that would require an action of $G$ on $Y$ which we don't have, so that would result in a "type error".)  And then, for instance you would want to prove $g \cdot (h \cdot f) = (gh) \cdot f$ by proving that for each $x$, $[g \cdot (h \cdot f)](x) = [(gh) \cdot f](x)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler's comment is very important as it highlights the relevance of parenthesis which a lot of people omit at the expense of clarity!

Comment: I think it is helpful to write the action of $g\in G$ on functions $f\colon X\to Y$ in the functional form, as $g\cdot f := f \circ g^{-1}$. Here ${\circ}$ is functional composition, $(f\circ h)(x):=f(h(x))$. It is then not difficult to prove that this action is indeed a *left action*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

$$\color{red}g\cdot\underbrace{(\color{blue}{h\cdot f})}_{k}(x)=\underbrace{\color{blue}{h\cdot f}}_{k}(\color{red}{g^{-1}}\cdot x)$$

by definition.

Comment: I see. So, we interpret $(h \cdot f)(x)$ as $k(x) \in Y^X$? I think my misunderstanding stemmed from the fact that I was viewing $h$ and $g$ as elements of the group $G$ acting on the element of the set $Y^X$ $f$ and not realizing that $(h \cdot f)(x) \in Y^X$. Since the equality after we consider $h$ to play the role of the group element again in the definition of the action given. Is there an intuitive way to see this?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Shaun. It is appreciated!

Comment: Careful, @NumericalDisintegration. Here $k\in Y^X$, while $k(x)\in Y$. It takes some getting-used-to. All you can do is practise.

Comment: You're welcome, @NumericalDisintegration :)